# DDD / Good practice to save many entities at once through repository

Tags: java, architecture, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

Basically, I have a `Notification` entity, representing user's notification on my app.

I expect a use case where the user can flag as "read" many notifications at once.

What I currently do is to get the collections of notifications, loop over them in order to specify a `notificationRepository.save(notification)` for each.   (`save` or even `add` if we strictly follow repository pattern essence to abstract database notion).

Under the cover, the repository implementation binds a **remote database**.

The issue is that it is very costly to make those round trips to my database server (since remote).
Indeed, if user expects to flag 10 notifications, there would be 10 round trips...

**Is there a way to batch those saving, while keeping DDD technical patterns rules?**
For example, should I define a `addAll` (or `saveAll`) method in my repository?

Comment: My Repository has a flush method which writes all pending changes to the database.  No need for a save method.

Comment: Read about unit of work.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, if you have an ORM or some sort of change tracker, you don't need `save()` methods on your repositories since modifications will be flushed at the application level, when the UnitOfWork is committed.

If 10 notifications were flagged, chances are the ORM will translate that into 10 update statements, but it's never been a problem to me. Maybe you can optimize that to do bulk updates though if it's really an issue.